# Approach including a Footer in every page using php

Tags: php, html, css

Hey all. i was wondering what is the best practice to include a footer
in all of my pages. i mean i have about 1000 of them. should i use the
php "include" function: `include 'static_footer.html'` or is it a bad practice ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have 1000 .php file pages, you may want to look into using an Model-View-Controller solution (like storing the page information in a database and using Code Igniter or something similar to display the information), or a Content Management System of some description.

But, as far as I know, your best bet would be to use the include() function.

```
include 'footer.php';
```

Answer (score 3):

There is always the option of using the [auto_append_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file) directive in php.ini to automatically include a file rather than modifying every single page

Comment: he has to modify because he has 1000 pages

Comment: @yes123 - sorry, I think I must have missed something here. It doesn't matter if he has 1 page or 1,000,000,000 pages, using an auto_append_file will automatically include a file at the end of every single PHP script execution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is perfectly fine to use an include function. This way, you'll be mimicking a sort of template engine, and it is a good way to avoid using the same code over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that is definitely a good idea, as it helps adhere to the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

Depending on your scenario, it might be worth looking at some php_value setting in a .htaccess file (if you're in a web environment). You can [auto_prepend](http://www.maheshchari.com/php-auto-append-prepend-file-using-htaccess/) a file to the output, which would save you adding an include statement to every file. This might not suit your needs, but for simple applications, it can.

Comment: No it's not a simple application, so i take the inculde function is alright. thanks all!

Comment: Fair enough. I would agree with ericissocial then, that MVC might be a good thing to look into.